# How can I get the app-related information from Facebook that passport-facebook requires?

Tags: passport.js, passport-facebook

At http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook , it says:

> In order to use Facebook authentication, you must first create an app at [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/). When created, an app is assigned an App ID and App Secret. Your application must also implement a redirect URL, to which Facebook will redirect users after they have approved access for your application.

I spent a bit of time exploring https://developers.facebook.com/ (linked to in the text), but I wasn't immediately able to track down:

1. Which type of app to create ("website" looks most obvious to me, but that's just on the level of "looks most obvious to me").
2. Where to determine your app's App ID.
3. Where to determine your app's App Secret.

How can that information be created / read?

Answer (score 0):

App Id and App secret are provided in the facebook application page. You can find that here https://developers.facebook.com/apps/.

The app id and app secret are provided through a verify callback through passport.

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , OAuthStrategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuthStrategy; 

passport.use('provider', new OAuthStrategy({   
    requestTokenURL: 'https://www.provider.com/oauth/request_token',
    accessTokenURL: 'https://www.provider.com/oauth/access_token',
    userAuthorizationURL: 'https://www.provider.com/oauth/authorize',
    consumerKey: '123-456-789',
    consumerSecret: 'shhh-its-a-secret'
    callbackURL: 'https://www.example.com/auth/provider/callback'
  },
```

**Verify Callback**

```
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```